# GRE textbooks question - calculus and linear algebra

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'll be taking the Math GRE subject test in a few months. I know that it is best to focus on being able to answer all the calculus, DEs, and linear algebra questions (and quickly). I'm a pure math student, so my computational skills and speed aren't so great because I'm out of practice.

I'm wondering what texts are best to prepare with. I know Stewart is commonly recommended for preparing for the calculus questions. My university used Calculus: Early Transcendentals by Edwards & Penney. I can get Stewart out of the library, so I was just wondering which would be a better resource (especially in terms of practice problems). Is Stewart sufficient for differential equations?

Secondly, what are some good linear algebra books? I have Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, but this doesn't teach much in the way of computational skills, so I need something that would be good for that.

I have also purchased the Princeton Review's Cracking the GRE Subject Test, which I've heard is not awesome but still worth having.

Comment: I think the Stewart book would better prepare you than the Edwards & Penney one.  Someone else might be able to help you with the other texts.

Comment: I think Linear Algebra by Friedberg, Insel and Spence is a good book to refer in this case.

Comment: I find it very strange that anybody preparing for the GRE would do so with a non-rigorous book like Stewart's. It would make more sense to use Volume 2 of Apostol's *Calculus*.

Comment: Howard Anton has a book _Calculus with Analytic Geometry: Linear Algebra_.

Comment: @user49640 This comment is both to you & the OP.  I was surprised by your comment; I own and love volumes 1 and 2 of Apostol's *Calculus*.  However, my impression is that the GRE test is about problem solving rather than rigorous proofs.  Since the OP seems to be under a time constraint my (**unproven**) intuition suggests that he would be better served by a non-rigorous approach.  To the OP: I googled "math gre subject test" and found online ref's that you can use for **practice.**  A brief look at these online references (1 of which featured a **multiple choice test**) prompted this comment.

Comment: @user49640 The GRE does not test mathematical rigor so using Apostol's Calculus would not be a good study guide.

To OP: go through practice tests in the various study guides available on the Internet or bookstore and you'll get a feel for the type of questions you will encounter. I would focus on problem solving skills, drawing conclusions from charts and graphs, and knowing the Math GRE question patterns.