# I have one month preparation. Please suggest some books.

Tags: calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

I have one month for my GRE subjective Mathematics test. I am from India. I have learnt $75\%$ of the syllabus in my UG and high school mentioned in the ETS. I am starting today, will I be able to finish in one month, Can you please suggest books to study from, even multiple books are welcome!! I need to score around $80\%$.

Comment: You might start by looking at: [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807285/multivariable-calculus-for-gre], [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91170/books-to-study-for-math-gre-self-study-have-some-time] or [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918684/gre-textbooks-question-calculus-and-linear-algebra].

Comment: Do you even require multivariable calculus and vector calculus .......  specify.

Comment: Yes I need all the books which are present in the syllabus. If you can suggest all the books, it would be very helpful.